# 1 функция с аргументом вместо двух, Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Я работаю с Nuxt JS. Я пытаюсь практиковать свои навыки в js, в коде есть пара функций с одинаковым функционалом только для разных элементов. Можно ли как-то объединить эти две функции в одной, сделать универсальную с передачей аргумента?

```js
 openOutSettings() {
    this.isOutOpen = !this.isOutOpen; 
  } 
  openInSettings() {
    this.isInOpen = !this.isInOpen; 
  }
```

Думала реализовать нечто похожее

```js
 openSettings(first, second) {
 if (first) {
    this.isOutOpen = !this.isOutOpen; } else {
    this.isInOpen = !this.isInOpen;}
  }
```

```html
<div @click="openSettings(first)"></div>
<div @click="openSettings(second)"></div>
```

Но этот код не работает для меня. Подскажите, как правильно написать универсальную функцию в моем случае?

Comment: Не работает, потому что функция не понимает что такое first и second, когда вы её вызываете, оберните аргумент который передаете в строку и проверяйте совпадение строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то вроде такого, хотя это и будет немного неправильно. Неправильно потому что явное - всегда лучше не явного.

```
 toogle(property) {
    this[property]= !this[property]; 
  } 

<div @click="toogle('isOutOpen')"></div>
<div @click="toogle('isInOpen')"></div>
```